# Storing the digits after the comma in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a double between `0` and `1` stored in an array in Matlab `B`.

I want to create a vector `t` storing the `N` digits after the comma. If the digits after the comma are `<N`, then the corresponding element in the vector `t` should be `0`.

Suppose `N=10` and `B=[0.908789]`. Then,

```
t=[9;0;8;7;8;9;0;0;0;0];
```

This is the code I am using at the moment

```
n = fix(rem(B,1)*10^N); 
s1 = sprintf('%.0f',n);
ttemp = (s1-'0')';
t=zeros(N,1);
t(1:size(ttemp,1))=ttemp;
```

but it gives me wrong results.

Indeed, suppose 
`B=[7.0261e-05]` and `N=5`. The code above gives me 
`t=[7;0;0;0]` without recognising that there `e-05`.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Well `fix(rem(B,1)*10^N)` yields `7` in your example and you fill in the result `t` starting at the beginning so it places *only a `7`* in your output at the beginning

Comment: Yes. The problem is that it gives me `7` and not `0 0 0 0 7`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell `sprintf` that you'd like all leading `0`'s to actually be shown if there are fewer than `N` digits:

Your current way:

```
sprintf('%.0f', n);
%   '7'
```

The correct way:

```
s1 = sprintf('%05.f', n);
%   '00007'
```

The general example for any `N` would be:

```
s1 = sprintf(['%0', num2str(N), '.f'],n);
```

The way that you currently have it written, the outpuf of the `sprintf` command is simply a `'7'` which when you fill in your output starting at the beginning yields a `7` followed by all `0`'s (the value you initialized the output to).

If we initialize it to `NaN` values instead of `0`'s you can see what the issue is

```
N = 5;
B = 7.0261e-05;

n = fix(rem(B,1)*10^N); 
%   7

s1 = sprintf('%.0f',n);
%  '7'

ttemp = (s1 - '0').';
%  7

t = nan(N, 1);
%  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

t(1:size(ttemp,1)) = ttemp;
%  7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Alternately, you can keep everything you have and just modify `t` from the *end* rather than the beginning

```
t = zeros(N, 1);
t((end-numel(ttemp)+1):end) = ttemp;
```

### Unsolicited Pointers

1. `'` is not the transpose, `.'` is.
2. Use `numel` to determine the number of elements in a vector rather than `size` since it will work for both row and column vectors

Comment: @user3285148 What don't you get? I've updated with the explicit output with and without the zero padding.

Comment: `s1 = sprintf(['%0', num2str(N), 'f'],n);` does not give me the leading zero.

Comment: @user3285148 Oops. Sorry, I left out a `'.'` in the format string .Updated now.